# php - Remove node and keeping it's content

Tags: php, xml

I have xml like this :

```
<parent>
  <0>
    <url>
      <loc>name1</loc>
      <date>monthly</date>
    </url>
  </0>
  <1>
    <url>
      <loc>alexJones</loc>
      <date>monthly</date>
    </url>
  </1>
</parent>
```

I want to remove `<0></0>` and `<1></1>` And new xml will be :

```
<parent>
    <url>
       <loc>name1</loc>
       <date>monthly</date>
    </url>
    <url>
       <loc>alexJones</loc>
       <date>monthly</date>
    </url>
</parent>
```

I've already knew that I can retrieve xml node using xml->children(),
but there is any suggestion for do this?

Comment: If you know the names or at least the patterns of the nodes, you may use str_replace or preg_replace

Answer (score 0):

That is an invalid XML, libxml will not load it. So this might be one of the exceptions where is valid to use regular expressions on an XML string.

```
$repairedXml = preg_replace('(</?\\d+>)', '', $invalidXml);
```

The pattern matches an tag consisting only of numbers and without attributes.

These tag names are invalid, a tag name can not start with a digit.